# Setting xml encoding attribute in prolog using .NET HttpClient

Tags: c#, xml, dotnet-httpclient, xml-encoding

Does anyone know if it's possible to set the encoding attr in the prolog when using C# HttpClient's PostAsXmlAsync method.

When I look at the requests in Fiddler I can see the encoding in the content-type http header, but I need in the prolog like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The XML declaration (what you call "prolog") is optional. When it states version 1.0 and encoding UTF-8, it's even redundant, because those values are the defaults.

In an HTTP transmission the authoritative information about payload encoding is given in the `Content-Type` header, so it's practical not to send a possibly conflicting piece of information in the payload itself.

So to me it looks as if the `HttpClientExtensions` class does the right thing.